# How to make nested accordian-like structure using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-accordion

Initially all the `accordian tabs` are disabled, upon selection of `Main Category` the subsequent `Sub Categories` should enabled and displayed.

1. Initial State
   [image: Initial State]
2. Upon Entering `some text` the `Main Category` enables
   [image: Main Categories]
3. Upon Selection `Main Category` the `Sub Category' enables and opens up.
4. [image]
   ... and So on

**Sorry for too many images**
I followed [this](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery) tutorial [here](http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Accordion-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/#accordion-1). On page load all tabs have expanded and no collaps-effect.

Comment: ...what is the question? How to make something like this?

Comment: Really looks like you want someone to make all job for you. It is not a question, but a billable task for a freelancer. You are on the wrong site.